# WebRTC: Is it supported in Safari & IE browsers?

Tags: webrtc, webm

I would to develop video streaming usign WebRTC. I have not heard about the browser compatibilities. Does it work in IE & MAC systems? Please advice the pros & cons of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works great on Mac systems using Firefox or Chrome. Safari doesn't support WebRTC yet.

IE doesn't support WebRTC also. Nevertheless, Microsoft claimed that IE will support WebRTC when standard had been finalized.

Regarding IE, take a look here, also: [Which version of Microsoft Internet Explorer support WebRTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724913/which-version-of-microsoft-internet-explorer-support-webrtc)

Comment: Can we make a connection between the system(i.e, Windows Firefox browser) and mobile devices(iPad and iPhone) using WebRTC?

Comment: As I know Chrome mobile supports WebRTC already. Opera doesn't yet(?). Regarding iOS - there is no native support yet. Nevertheless, you can use 3rd-party browser/software.

Comment: OK. I've been using SimpleWebRTC. It doesn't work in HTTP mode. I've hosted it in HTTPS. Since, it doesn't. Any Idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question, sorry. I've neveer used SimpleWebRTC, so can't advise anything. If you need any framework/example to develop WebRTC application, you can take alook on my project: https://github.com/fycth/webrtcexample

Comment: OK. Does your application allow us to do "one to many" communication? Can we communicate from different devices(iPhone, iPad & Desktop)? Please advice. Thanks for your kind information. Best wishes for your project.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than [just] providing an answer that will surely go out of date at some point, let me point you to CanIUse.com:

### http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc

Currently, as of 2015-08-14, WebRTC is still completely missing from Safari (OS X & iOS) and from IE (including Edge).

Answer (score 1):

**Safari**

Apple announced support for WebRTC in Safari 11.

You can download the latest beta version of Safari 11 at the following link:
(You need to sign in with your Apple ID) https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

**Microsoft Edge**

Edge supports webRTC with the help of [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter).

**Internet explorer**

You'll need a 3rd party plugin, like Skylink or Temasys.