# QuickBlox application on IE11 with a plugin?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webrtc, quickblox, temasys

We are developing a chat application with QuickBlox JavaScript SDK. However, for application to be able to run on IE11 we need a plugin. We have tried Temasys webRTC plugin for IE but it doesn't work with QuickBlox. Is there any plugin that can successfully run QuickBlox application on IE? Is it possible to run QuickBlox app on IE (even with a plugin)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the QuickBlox document](https://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript), the QuickBlox support the following browser:

[image]

and with [this article](https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-web) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555839/webrtc-is-it-supported-in-safari-ie-browsers), we can see that WebRTC is unsupported in IE. So, I suggest you could try to use Edge browser.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Requirements from the client was to support IE, but we'll need to inform them to drop it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get a WebRTC based application running on IE11 with the Temasys Plugin (I implemented it for my application a few weeks ago). Of course QuickBlox is stating that they won't support IE11 since it doesn't have a build in support for WebRTC.

Keep in mind that Temasysplugin isn't for free, is currently in a change freeze and is using the deprecated API (callback instead of promises). Also keep in mind that this won't be easy e.g. shimming away the differences between the browsers.

Edit: Maybe you can state why Temasysplugin didn't work with QuickBlox, if there is really no way getting it to work you probably have to tell your customer that IE11 isn't supported